# Limit superior of a sequence of random variables and its probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am following a course on Stochastic Processes and in the solution of an exercise I have found a statement like the following:

> $$\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\to \infty} X_n \geq c) \leq \mathbb{P}(X_n \geq c, i.o.) $$

where $(X_n)$ is a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, but I guess this is not very important) and I really cannot see why this is true.

I must confess that I have not a clear idea of what a limit superior is, but it seems to me like a "progressive approssimation from below" hence my intuition led me to the idea that the inequality above should hold for the limit inferior rather than the limit superior.

I am aware of the horribly wrong intuition I have built up, does anyone have good suggestions to understand this object in a better (and correct) way?

Comment: The fact that every $X_n$ is integer valued is crucial to the inequality, otherwise, one would only have $$\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n\to \infty} X_n \geq c\right) \leq \mathbb{P}(X_n \geq c-\epsilon\ \text{infinitely often})$$ for every positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: Not a whiff of (stochastic-calculus) here, please watch your tags.

Comment: "I have not a clear idea of what a limit superior is" Why don't you? There is a **definition**, you know...

Comment: Definitions have to be understood, or did you get immediately a clear idea of the behaviour of every object you' ve encountered in you life as a mathematician?

Comment: Not sure your rhetorical question deserves an answer. What is this definition already and which precise aspect of it do you find difficult to grasp? These are features of the problem which, if added to your question, could make it acceptable (and answerable).

Comment: what is one exactly looking for taking the limit superior of a sequence of random variables? what is the difference between $limsup$ and the actual pointwise limit? why, intuitively, its behaviour gives informations on the whole process (even for n very small)?

Comment: As I already said, one has to start from the definition of limsup to understand limsup. I note that, when explicitely asked for this definition, you skirt this demand and fall back on imprecise or even difficult to understand expressions ("even for n very small", excuse me?). Would you be actually  lacking this definition? Then say so... Anyway, until you come back to a more standard way of learning maths, the case is closed as far as I am concerned.

Comment: you did possibly not understand my problem, the definition does not say anything to me, more explicitly it does not say the things I wrote before. If you want to help me, I would really thank you, otherwise you can just avoid to answer.
Ps "There is a definition, you know..." is not really a demand, it is more a pseudo-sarcastic gratuitous comment

Comment: "you did possibly not understand my problem" I think I understand exactly where you stand (and I happen to disagree with this standpoint). "not really a demand, it is more a pseudo-sarcastic gratuitous comment" Your interpretation. One could also say this points at exactly the aspect of the situation that you want to avoid at all cost admitting, which is that simply reading the definitions involved would allow you to reach the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_n=c-1/n$, the probability of the left hand side is $1$ while that of the right hand side is zero.

It turns out that in general, the following inclusion holds, whatever the random variables $X_n$ are:
$$\left\{X_n\geqslant c\mbox{ infinitely often}\right\}\subseteq \left\{\limsup_{n\to +\infty}     X_n\geqslant c\ \right\}, $$
which is due to the fact that if $\left(a_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $a_n\geqslant c$ infinitely often, then $\limsup_{n\to +\infty}a_n\geqslant c$.

Comment: doesn't this imply the reverse inequality?